# oauth2.0 for user profile info

Tags: android, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

how can i use oauth2.0 to get users google profile info on android app. I need the proper code/ example for an android app. I need the users information like :

1. profile photo
2. birthday
3. gender
4. location

Thanks

Comment: hey, if you have done this, can you please share, how did you come up with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google OAuth will require the following steps:

1.Register with Google [here](https://code.google.com/apis/console/?pli=1#access). after registering ,in the `INSTALLED APPLICATION` section you will get your `REDIRECT_URI` and `CLIENT_ID`

2.The `REDIRECT_URI` and `CLIENT_ID` obtained above now will be used in the following url.

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?" + "scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.email+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.profile"+ "&redirect_uri=" + REDIRECT_URI + "&response_type=code" +"&client_id=" + CLIENT_ID;
```

3.This url will take you to the Google Authentication page, here google takes over and you enter your account details. Further, it is redirected to the approval page, where the user allows your app to use their google data.

4.Now, as a response to this you get `ACCESS CODE` from google as a JSON or in the title of the html page. Parse the `ACCESS CODE`.

5.With the `ACCESS CODE` you will now make a `POST` request with the following post data to get the `ACCESS TOKEN`.

```
'code' // this is the access code
'client_id' // same as earlier
'client_secret' // you will find this on the google page where you registered
'redirect_uri' // same as earlier
'grant_type' = "authorization_code" // as is
```

6.You will now get the ACCESS TOKEN in a JSON as "access_token" . parse this access token.

7.Make use of the Access token to make a call on the following url

```
https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo?alt=json&access_token=your_access_token_here
```

8.You will  get the users data as a response to this call as a JSON.

Here are additional docs that you may need:
https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2InstalledApp

Comment: i am trying this since a long time... but cant understand how to code for this. I am trying to use GoogleAuthUtil.getToken()

Comment: Thank you so much !.. ur steps helped me accomplish the task. I used GoogleAuthUtil. Not much documentation is available for this. I will put up my code asap for others. :)